# Error SOAP with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, soap, web-applications, cors

thank you for helping, i know there is a lot of people who has this kind of issues, but i've tried a lot of ways to solve it.

What i want is to send and receive from this simple html5 file, so i could "translate" with phonegap to WebApp.

The problem is the typical issue "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I have a SOAP service and the structure must work like follow:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=”http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/”>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<m:Query xmlns:m=”http://www.incits.org/RTLS/">
<QueryName>RTLS_Blinks</QueryName>
<FilterBy>
<RTLSBlinkTime><![CDATA[>2010-12-01T00:00:00Z]]></ RTLSBlinkTime>
<OR/>
<BatteryLow>=true</BatteryLow>
<Blinking>=true</Blinking>
</FilterBy>
<Fields> TagID Location BatteryLow </Fields>
<SortBy>
<Field>TagID</Field>
<Order>asc</Order>
</SortBy>
</m:Query>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and the response must be something like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV= ”http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/”>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<m:QueryResponse xmlns:m=”http://www.incits.org/RTLS/">
<QueryResult>
<NumItems>1</NumItems>
<TagBlinks> 
<TagBlink>
<TagID>0004A32BEF24</TagID>
<Location>
    <X>157</X>
    <Y>359</Y>
    <Z>2</Z>
</Location>
<States>
    <BatteryLow>=true</BatteryLow>
</States>
</TagBlink>
</TagBlinks>
</QueryResult>
```

My code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Hago pruebas del SOAP de Balmart</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#btEnviar").click(function() { llamarWebService(); return false;});
});
var soapMessage;
function llamarWebService() {
    soapMessage = "<?xml version='1.0'" + ' encoding="utf-8"?>'; 
    soapMessage += '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope ';
    soapMessage+= 'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ';
    soapMessage += 'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ';
    soapMessage += 'xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'; 
    soapMessage += "<SOAP-ENV:Body>"; 
    //[Add your xml here] 
    soapMessage+= '<m:Query xmlns:m="http://www.incits.org/RTLS/">';
    soapMessage+= '<QueryName>RTLS_BLinks</QueryName>';
    soapMessage+='<FilterBy/>';
    soapMessage+='<Fields/>';
    soapMessage+='<SortBy><Field>TagID</Field><Order>asc</Order></SortBy>';
    soapMessage+= '</m:Query">';
    // [End]
    soapMessage += "</SOAP-ENV:Body>"; 
    soapMessage += "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"; 
    $("#info").html("Request:" + soapMessage).append("<br />");
    var laUrl='http://test.balmart.es:8080';
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: laUrl,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        crossDomain:true,
        data: soapMessage,
        success: exitoWebService,
        error: errorWebService,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
}
function exitoWebService(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $("#info").append("&Eacute;xito: " + data);
}
function errorWebService(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
    $("#info").append("Error: " + textStatus + " - " + error);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2 for="texto">Hola Caracola¡¡¡</h2>
<button id="btEnviar">Enviar</button>
<p>
    El mensaje enviado es el siguiente:
    <br/>
    <small id="mensaje"></small>
</p>
<div id="info"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, what can i do to solve the issue and receive the data ? Remember that the soap response is xml and no JSON.

And i dont wanna make vulnerable the site including dangerous "allow access '*'... " on php.
Help please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only problem with that request is the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header then you are good to go. I bet you haven't tried doing the request from an actual phone since phonegap apps won't complain about that header.
You can also start chrome in 'unsafe mode' and try doing the request. first kill any chrome process and open it again with `chromium-browser --disable-web-security`(it's chromium in my case).